# Show Unicode characters in text field

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unicode, slider, nstextfield

I have a slider for testing and I want the characters represented by the slider position to be shown in a text field. But my text field only shows A-Z and a-z when running my solution below. How can I get Unicode characters into my text field?

```
- (IBAction) doSlider: (id) sender
    {
        long long theNum = [sender intValue];
        NSString *vc_theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", theNum];
        [charField      setStringValue:vc_theString2];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%c` is inherited from C and limited to an 8-bit range. You should use `%C`, which will read in the corresponding argument as a `unichar`.